# Is there a tool to extract documentation/comments from CommonJS or node.JS modules?

Tags: node.js, documentation, comments

So for example:

```
/** This is my foo method, it's great. */
exports.foo = function(a, b) {
    return a + b;
};
```

Would be great to have something that scans a directory of .js source and builds documentation, listing the methods of each module along with their associated description comments, perhaps an overview comment for a whole module, and also look for `require` calls so as to show the dependencies between modules.

Answer (score 0):

Tonight I've authored [this tiny tool](https://github.com/1602/makedoc).
It allows you to build [something like this](http://1602.github.com/jugglingdb/abstract-class.html)
using [this code](https://github.com/1602/jugglingdb/blob/master/lib/abstract-class.js) as source.

It's not fully-featured jsdoc parser, I think all of these fully features totally sucks, because generated docs too trashy, flooded with unnecessary structuring.

My tool build for flat code that looks like a book, and not like a deep tree.

Comment: Does it look at the `requires` to build a picture of the relationships between modules? That I think is the specific bit of structural information that is available to be extracted from commonjs/node modules to build a picture of their interdependencies.

Comment: At the moment it doesn't care about `require`, because I trying to keep it as simple as possible. I don't see any real-world cases for this information. Most of modules require same things inside single module. Best information about cross-modules dependencies available at `npm ls` output.

Comment: But if `npm ls` is not solution for your case, feel free to share your thoughts, maybe I'm missing something. It's not big deal to implement this feature, if it's really needed.

Answer (score 0):

You should really look into [docco](http://jashkenas.github.com/docco/). It's designed to do the "literate-programming" style documentation you're describing and to produce *very nice* looking documentation out of it.

The page I linked you to is docco parsing itself, by the way.

Comment: It looks very nice but I can't see anything in the source that looks for `requires` to recognise dependencies between modules to build an overview of a system of interdependent source files and show which depends on what.

Comment: Should that really be a part of your source documentation? I'd think it'd make more sense to just use a shell script to parse that out and then pipe it into GraphViz to make a pretty dependency graph.